# Generate std::array types and store them for runtime use

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming

I have a wrapper class which is templated on the container type I am using, which may be an std::array of some size:

```
 //! @tparam C the random access container type to be wrapped. E.g.
 //! std::vector, or std::array.
 template<class C>
 class MyWrapper
 {
  public:
    ...

     //! @return the maximum number of elements that can be stored by the wrapped
     //! container.
     static size_t cardinality();
 }
```

Now, I can create this wrapper using an std::array at compile time. All good so far. The problem is that this wrapper will then be sent to another module over the network( serialized using protobuf and grpc). Now, I can send the type of the container, size and the data it carries. For instance, if I have an object of type `Wrapper<std::array<double, 6>>`, I can send the information  about this being a wrapper for an std::array, of size six, which carries doubles.

The problem is that on the *receiver* side, I have to re-create the exact same object. But I cannot have e.g. a function that takes a size and type argument and creates an array at run time, e.g.

```
template<class T>
createArr(size_t n)
{
   MyWrapper<std::array<T, n>> arr;
   ...
}
```

Thus, my idea is that I should be able to generate some std::array types at compile time, store them in a lookup table and use this table to create arrays at runtime. This will have the constraints that I will only be able to support a limited number of types and  sizes, e.g.:

```
std::array<int, 1>
std::array<int, 2>
...
std::array<int, 1000>

std::array<double, 1>
std::array<double, 2>
...
std::array<double, 1000>
```

but I am okay with that.

Is there any way of doing this, e.g. using template metaprogramming?

**EDIT**: If I do something like this:

```
template<class T, int n>
createArr()
{
   MyWrapper<std::array<T, n>> arr;
   ...
}
```

This means that I will have to have a template declaration for each type and size, something I want to avoid writing out plainly in the code, since I have so many types and sizes...that's why I thought it would be possible to generate these somehow.

Comment: Pass the size of the array as a termplate argument instead of a function argument? Function arguments are run-time.

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to declare all the possible template types I guess? If I want to support arrays from size 1 to 1000, for each type, that will be a lot of declarations...This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Perhaps `std::array` just isn't the correct container for this use-case?

Comment: Well, unfortunately it is not something I can change, since it was implemented by other programmers at work...and it is not easy to change due to various reasons.

Comment: `std::array` is for fixed sized types, `std::vector` is if you don't know the size

Comment: Elaborate on your use case, please. That what you're trying to achieve can be done either by means of multiple inheritance (for "all the needed types" case) or variant, either from boost or std (for "one out of many at at time" case), but you need to be more specific about what exactly is needed. Live demos for some inspiration: https://godbolt.org/z/Pea8ab4ob (by no means exhaustive, neither complete nor optimal, more like quick and dirty "see if it works").

Comment: You could make it so the receiver makes a std::vector even though the sender used std::array?

Comment: @alagner Thanks for the suggestion! But this your code still forces me to specify the size at compile time, e.g. auto y = x.get<3>(), which will force one to write  x.get<0>(),  x.get<1>()... x.get<1000>(). I need something like a function which will take a size argument and return that array type when asked for, i.e. something like  
decltype(x.get(1000)) arr;